# Why subprocess continue to live when stdout and stderror are file handlers?

Tags: python, subprocess

When I run a very simple script with subprocess the subprocess is terminated once following script ends.

```py
import subprocess
import os
import tempfile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subproc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'tcpdump', '-c', '10000'])
    print(subproc.pid)
```

`ps -p <pid>` shows no such process

But when I modify the script to use handlers for stdout and stderror it continue to run until it finishes its job.

```
import subprocess
import os
import tempfile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(os.getpid())
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as stderr, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as stdout:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'tcpdump', '-c', '10000'], stderr=stderr, stdout=stdout)
    print(proc.pid)
```

`ps -p <pid>` shows subprocess is still running for some time.
Not sure why is that and whether I could rely that my subprocess will always finish in the second sample.

Tested in python 2.7 and 3.7 macos and debian.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  Does it only happen with `tcpdump`?  Does it happen if you remove the `sudo` and run the script with `sudo` instead?  If it only happens with `tcpdump` it could be using `isatty()` to distinguish between these cases and changing its behavior.